# Given the arc length of a function and the lower limit, how to find the upper limit?

Tags: integration, arc-length

Given any arbitrary function $f(x)$, its arc length in the interval $[a,b]$ is defined as:

$$
s=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+(\nabla f(x))^2}\,dx,
$$

i.e., we integrate the above expression from $a$ to $b$, using the first derivative of the function $f(x)$.

**Question**: if $a,s$ are known, how to get $b$? In other words, I already have the arc length, and I do know from where it was measured (the beginning of the interval) - how to get $b$? $f(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x)$ are not analytical expressions, rather, I am doing numerical computations.

Comment: What will you do with  known function and derivative but no explicit antiderivative for $\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}$ ?

Comment: I am only interested in obtaining $b$, the upper limit of the integral expression. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I was just pointing the fact that even if we know $f'(x)$ we are in trouble. All this problem is strictly numerical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we know the derivative but
$$I=\int \sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}\,dx$$ is not analytical. Suppose that $I$ is analytical but cannot be inversed. What can be done beside numerical calculations ?

But the is not bad in the first case since Newton will perfect. We want to find the zero of function
$$F(b)=s -\int_a^b \sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}\,dx$$
$$F'(b)=-\sqrt{1+[f'(b)]^2}$$
$$b_{k+1}=b_k+\frac{s -\int_a^{b_k} \sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}\,dx } {\sqrt{1+[f'(b_k)]^2} }$$ the *worst* initial estimate being
$$b_0=a+\frac s{\sqrt{1+[f'(a)]^2} }$$

Just for illustration, using $f(x)=\text{erf}(x)$, $a=-1$ and $s=123.456$
So
$$F(b)=123.456-\int_{-1}^b \sqrt{1+\frac{4 }{\pi }e^{-2 x^2}}\,dx$$  Being very lazy, I shall start the above $b_0$ and the solution is obtained in $2$ iterations for $50$ exact significant figures.

Comment: Excellent! I had not thought about that, but it works great. Did an implementation in R to verify it.

Comment: @user654123. It must since the worst estimate is good !

Comment: Just for the sake of it, I started with another initial estimate for $b_0$: In my scenario, I want to subdivide the arc ($s$) into $N$ equally long sections, so I started with $b_0=s/N$.